# segmentation fault core dumped gcc codeblocks

Tags: c, gcc

Well, i have problem with ubuntu system, i'm sure my code does not have any errors but i recive `segmentation fault` while i'm trying to use `fseek` on big text file, very big because its bible. and gdb says `fseek.c no such file or directory`. So someone can tell me how can i, in codeblocks set more memory for my program because i think its memory problem, or maybe You have other ideas?
I have tryied usint `ulimit` with many options but i cant set bigger limits

```
void odpalBiblie()
{
    char *file_contents;
    long input_file_size;
    FILE *input_file = fopen("BIBLIA.TXT", "rb");
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    input_file_size = ftell(input_file);
    rewind(input_file);
    file_contents = malloc(input_file_size * (sizeof(char)));
    fread(file_contents, sizeof(char), input_file_size, input_file);
    fclose(input_file);
    cnt_words(file_contents, 1000);
}
```

here is function which cause segmentation fault and it happens exactly at `fseek`

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: You are not checking if `fopen()` returned an error. If the file was not opened, the calling `fseek` may be undefined behavior.

Comment: can you show `cnt_words` too.

Comment: i can but this does not make sense since this function is not even called because error happens erlier

Comment: How do you know that? in `cnt_word` you could be using something like `strlen` and you haven't `'\0'` terminated the read string, that will be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need more memory but certainly your program has the potential to cause a few segmentation faults, because your code is very unsafe, this would be the safe version of your program

```
void odpalBiblie()
{
    char *file_contents;
    long  input_file_size;
    FILE *input_file;

    input_file = fopen("BIBLIA.TXT", "rb");
    if (input_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: el archivo BIBLIA.TXT no se puedo abrir.\n");
        return;
    }
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);

    input_file_size = ftell(input_file);

    rewind(input_file);
    /* 1 + input_file_size por el '\0' que debe ir al final */
    file_contents = malloc(1 + input_file_size);
    if (file_contents == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: el sistema no tiene suficiente memoria.\n");
        fclose(input_file);

        return;
    }
    /* si vas a usar cualquier función del header strnig.h 
    * debes sellar el buffer con '\0'.
    */
    file_contents[input_file_size] = '\0';

    fread(file_contents, 1, input_file_size, input_file);    
    fclose(input_file);

    cnt_words(file_contents, 1000);
}
```

you must check for every possible failure, for example in case the file does not exist or it's not readable by the current user, you will have undefined behavior, which could cause a segmentation fault.

**Check every function that can theoretically fail to avoid problems, no matter how unlikely failure will happen.**

Comment: @whd always check for possible errors, I was almost sure the problem had to do with that.